# What is the regular language for L = {w | w has even length, and starts and ends with the same symbol}?

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

I think it is it `0(01)*(01)*0 U 1(01)*(01)1` where:

- two versions: one that starts and ends with 0, the other that starts and ends with 1
- connected by plus, which does **not mean union of both but either or**
- repeat of `(01)*` to make the string even. For example, for `0010` you would

1. start with 0
2. pick 0 from the first `01s`
3. pick 0 from the second `01s`
4. end with 0

**UPDATE:**
**I think this is a more clear and accurate answer:
(0+1)(00+11+01+10)∗(0+1)**

0+1: You choose either 0 or 1

00 + 11 +01 + 10: All possible options for an even lenght

0+1: last symbol as first

Comment: You wouldn't get the entire language $L$. For example, how would you get `0110`?

Comment: @TheoBendit, the (01)* represents either pick 0 or 1 with kleene star. So for 0110, you would start off with 0, pick the two 1s from (01)* and end with 0

Comment: That's usually written $(0+1)^\ast$, not as $(01)^\ast$.

Comment: Anyway, $(0+1)^\ast(0+1)^\ast$ does _not_ necessarily have even length. There's nothing forcing the two $(0+1)^\ast$ sections to be the same length.

Comment: @MJD, thank you, I fixed the language based on (0+1) and explained my thought. I also included another way (in the post) that I think it correct (and more clear).

Comment: @coolcat $(0+1)(00+11+01+10)^*(0+1)$ is also allowing $0111$. Which shouldn't be in $L$. And besides I think that cs.stackexchange.com would be better for that kind of question.

Comment: @DavidKrell This is pure mathematics and is 100% suitable for this site.  That's why we have tags for [tag:regular-expressions] and [tag:regular-language].

Comment: @MJD I think I got it: 

1((0+1)(0+1))*1 + 0((0+1)(0+1)*)0

Comment: I think that works.  Note that $(0+1)(0+1) = (00+01+10+11)$ because concatenation distributes over union.

Answer (score 1):

Your original $$\begin{align}&(0(0+1)^\ast(0+1)^\ast0) +\\ &(1(0+1)^\ast(0+1)^\ast1)
\end{align}$$ suggestion gets part of the requirements correct: every string begins and ends with the same symbols.  But it doesn't get the even-length requirement right, because there is nothing about $(0+1)^\ast(0+1)^\ast$ that forces the two groups to have the same length.  The first one could have 7 symbols and the other could have 12, and then the total length would be 19, which you don't want.

Your second suggestion,
$$(0+1)(00+11+01+10)^\ast(0+1)$$ gets the length requirement right, but doesn't guarantee that every string has the same beginning and ending symbol, because there is nothing that forces the two $(0+1)$ parts to produce the same symbol.  One could be $0$ and the other could be $1$.

You need to combine these two ideas.